# Best way to archive (delete) MongoDB data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a webpage for doctors where there are doctors, patients, and diagnoses stored in the database. There is an option to delete either of these entries (e.g. delete a doctor instance), but in, order to avoid data loss, I want to archive the data instead of deleting it entirely. I have found 2 options to do these:

1 - Keep an archive collection (e.g. doctors-archive, patients-archive) to move the entry there from the original collection.

2 - Keep an attribute isDeleted inside the original collection, so when an entry is deleted, isDeleted will become true, and when fetching the entries with isDeleted=true will not be returned.

Both of these options have their drawbacks - 1st option makes it hard to keep relations, as the patient and doctor have relations and if one of them is deleted the relation will be lost. The second option makes the original collection too heavy as the data will never be removed from it.

Is there a better option than these 2 to store archived data? If not, which of these options are better?

Answer (score 2):

It's a very good discussion. I had the same confusion in one of my projects, and after a long research I found a solution that fit well my needs.

First of all, I found that the **suppression is not reputed**, developers avoid this action to avoid data loss wrongly.

Furthermore, the suppression of data has another disadvantages:

1. It will lead to having **more data** into your system, because you will create new models & collections (e.g., doctors-archive model for doctors model).
2. This will have a significant **impact on the performance** of the system: the suppression will be done after 3 (and may be more) queries:

> find(): to select the object to be deleted.
>
> insert(): to create an archive instance for the object to be deleted.
>
> delete(): to delete the object.

*Note that we can not use the `findOneAndDelete()` method since we have to create an archive instance before !*

Contrariwise, the second option can be done by 1 query: `findAndModify()`.

But, the best solution is not the first one, nor the second one ! But a **combination of both of them**: it consists of **cleaning your data after a specific period** (every 4 months for example).

In other worlds, when deleting an instance, you apply the 2nd solution (i.e., isDeleted = true), but after 4 months, you can delete this instance from the collection and keep a copy in the archive (also called **backup**). This solution will prevent the original collection from being too heavy.

Note that you can also have a **separately backup** database to avoid use of the originale database.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these options have their drawbacks - 1st option makes it hard to keep relations, as the patient and doctor have relations and if one of them is deleted the relation will be lost. The second option makes the original collection too heavy as the data will never be removed from it. => What kind of relationship are you talking about?

If you still need a document post it is archived there has to be a middle ground there and by the why in those scenarios the data isn't lost you still have the power to do $lookup.

Based on my experience the option 2 has way too many negatives, it leads often to range index scans and on top of it you are maintaining extra burden for the indexes too where isDeleted will become part of every index you create.

TLDR; Definitely option 1 and if you need to query on archived content then use $lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The relationship is the _id, I keep, for instance, the doctor's id in diagnosis collection, so if the doctor is deleted the diagnosis will lose the reference to doctor's id

Comment: I got your point, denormalise the necessary content from the doctor collection in diagnosis collection. For example, a doctor getting archived means the doctor is not with you guys anymore but the diagnosis is open, denormalise content which will keep the diagnosis relevant. And I am guessing you guys are archiving doctor so that it is not shown as available option to people using the system. @TigranMinasyan

Answer (score 0):

There are some techniques for mongodb which you can use to manage data growth in MongoDB:

- Using capped collection
- Using TTLs
- Using multiple collections for months( rename old one and keep data in new one only)